# Clear part of an IPython cell's output

Tags: ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Before I get reamed for this, I know there are some posts detailing how to clear ALL the output from a cell, but I'm interested in only clearing part of it.

Let me provide some background.  I am creating a word-guessing game like LINGO where the user is prompted to guess a five-letter word, then using CSS to provide some visual feedback as to which letters are in the correct position, and which letters are in the word but in the wrong position. The way my program is structured, it displays the feedback after each guess and then prompts the user again and displays the guess.  So something like this:

Guess a word: word

FEEDBACK

guess again: word

FEEDBACK
...

You get the picture. My goal is to come as close to duplicating LINGO as possible, which would mean removing the user input from the screen after it has been submitted and having it show a sequence of feedback.  This to me means one of three things:

1) Find a way to clear part of the output

2) Find a way to prompt the user for text input without displaying it on the screen

3) Cache the user input, delete the all the output after each iteration, and display the cached guesses.

I've researched 1 and 2 and haven't been able to find anything.  3 would be a PITA so before I went to the trouble I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 0):

1 think is either not possible or very difficult - it's hard in regular python, never mind Jupyter. In regular python, you'd probably use something like `curses` but I tried it in Jupyter and it affects the console Jupyter is running from - not the stdout in the notebook.

If you really wanted 2, you could probably write your own version of `input` that uses carriage return `\r` after stripping the trailing newline via writing a function that loops listening for keystrokes and submitting once a newline is pressed. The carriage return should mean that the next line overwrites the previous line.

3 Caching the input shouldn't be too difficult though I presume? Just store them in an array or something then you can display them back to the user after using `IPython.display.clear_output`.